# define a function for each array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to do this without writing the code X times. How you do that in JavaScript ? I am from Java.

```
        floors[0].on("up_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[0].floorNum());
        } );
        floors[0].on("down_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[0].floorNum());
        } );

        floors[1].on("up_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[1].floorNum());
        } );
        floors[1].on("down_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[1].floorNum());
        } );

        floors[2].on("up_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[2].floorNum());
        } );
        floors[2].on("down_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[2].floorNum());
        } );        

        floors[3].on("up_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[3].floorNum());
        } );
        floors[3].on("down_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[3].floorNum());
        } ); 

        floors[4].on("up_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[4].floorNum());
        } );
        floors[4].on("down_button_pressed", function() { 
            elevator.goToFloor(floors[4].floorNum());
        } );
```

Comment: Why does every individual floor have its own `on` event? There should be one event listener and the event should contain the information which button was pressed on which floor. Then the elevator can go to that floor.

Comment: it s a game  : http://play.elevatorsaga.com/#challenge=3 I don t control the settings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in

```
floors[0].on("up_button_pressed", function () { 
     elevator.goToFloor(floors[0].floorNum());
});
```

the `floors[0]` inside the function is always the same object that the one that is triggering the event, so I would change it to use `this`:

```
floors[0].on("up_button_pressed", function () { 
        elevator.goToFloor(this.floorNum());
});
```

and then, just do it for all floors with `forEach`:

```
floors.forEach(function (floor) {
    floor.on("up_button_pressed", function () {
        elevator.goToFloor(this.floorNum());
    });
    // same for "down_button_pressed" here
});
```

Since handler functions do not need to access outer variable `floor` and use `this`, you can even define them out of loop and use them by name, if you wished:

```
function onFloorUp() {
    elevator.goToFloor(this.floorNum());
}
// same for onFloorUp

floors.forEach(function (floor) {
    floor.on("up_button_pressed", onFloorUp);
    // same for "down_button_pressed" here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just make use of `Array.forEach` and refactor your code to the below

```
floors.forEach(function(floor){
    floor.on('up_button_pressed,down_button_pressed', function(){
       elevator.goToFloor(floor.floorNum());
    });
});
```

You're not doing anything specific when when `up_button_pressed` or `down_button_pressed` is triggered, so just combine those events using a comma.

Answer (score 1):

here we go...
first you take one of your function that you need to be iterated.

```
floors[0].on("up_button_pressed", function() { 
        elevator.goToFloor(floors[0].floorNum());
    } );
```

then you transform that code so that code can work in iteration (for example for loop)

```
for(var i=0; i<x; i++){
floors[i].on("up_button_pressed", function(i) { 
    elevator.goToFloor(floors[i].floorNum());
}, i ); }
```

I do that on casperjs, but I think that will be work on regular javascript too...(because casperjs is javascript too)